# Regular Expression - How to create

Tags: c#, regex, data-annotations

I'm looking to write a regular expression and my research online is taking me all over the place.  Here's what I'm looking to do:

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression("MyRegExString", ErrorMessage = "Use only valid characters.")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

I want to allow my users to enter any alpha character (capital or lower case), and number, have spaces, and only _ (underscore), $, #, *, (, ), +, @, , (comma), and ' (apostrophe).

Can anyone help me generate this string?

Comment: `"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"` will get satisfy the first two requirements.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks, John.  Was not aware of that.  Will remember for next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just enter them all into a character class and require that they the whole string consists of characters from this class (by putting `^` and `$` anchors at the beginning and end, respectively):

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9_ $#*()+@,']*$"
```

Regular expressions also have a built-in character class `\w` that matches letter (lower and upper case), digit or underscore, allowing for this slightly shorter version:

```
"^[\w $#*()+@,']*$"
```

Use `+` instead of `*` at the end if you want to disallow empty strings.

Comment: Yup, I just didn't want to bluntly copy that optimization from you :D. But if you insist ;)

Answer (score 1):

`\w` represents any alpha character, digit or underscore. Rest has to be added one by one, but in some environments dollar sign should be escaped by `\`, as without that it wold represents end of string. Sign `^` represents beginning of the string. Star `*` has meaning of "none or more" and `[...]` has meaning "any of the characters inside".

```
^[\w \$#*()+@,']*$
```

Comment: In fact, `$` does not count as a meta-character within character classes. [Only these do](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html): `]^\-` ... I just escaped it in my answer, because I was not sure... I'll edit that now.

Comment: @m.buettner - As it says in my post: **"in some environments"** ... and it doesn't hurt anyway.

Comment: Oh sorry, I overlooked that you said that. That's definitely a good point then!

Answer (score 0):

Go with `^[a-zA-Z]+$` and add whatever charecters you want inside of `[...]`.

Some special characters need to be escaped by `\`.

Example:

```
/^[a-zA-Z!”$%&’()*\+,\/;\[\\\]\^_{|}~]+$/
```

Comment: "^[a-zA-Z <what ever charecter you need > ]+$"

Comment: please make your answer legible and add some explanation.

Comment: /^[a-zA-Z0-9 <add charecters that you want to allow> ]+$/

Comment: a-zA-Z0-9 would allow chars and numbers and replace <add charecters that you want to allow> with the chatecters like +-* what ever that you want to allow that will do

Comment: why don't you edit these explanations into the answer instead of posting them in a comment?